# Lo4net in a Windows service

Tags: c#-4.0, log4net

I have a C# solution which contains three services and a number of projects. I added a class for [Log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) which calls configuration details from an SQL table. I am using the same class for logging in my entire project.

The logging is working fine when I debug through the code, but when I deploy it in a server and while it works using the service, the logging is not working properly. I have three services and logging depends on which service I start first. If I start service 1 first, it logs only details from that service's classes, and it doesn't log other classes.

I tried to add `Idisposable` in the logger class and to destroy it each time, but I am not getting the expected results.

Comment: Not sure but I think you need to register logger for each service start. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Add your Assemble(ClassName) in your Appender:

> ```
> <appender name="UrlAppender3" type="OmidLogAppender.UrlLogAppender, OmidLogAppender">
> ```

that OmidLogAppender is my Log4net Class That Log into  Another Web Service !